# Solve multiple Equations using Z3

Tags: python, z3

I have the following function which accepts an input string and a number to generate a hash as shown below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

def calc_hash(key, num):
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(key)):
        result = (ord(key[i]) + result * 10 - 0x30) % num

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print hex(calc_hash("you_must_check_this_out", 0x1A5D215))
```

So, if the input string is: "you_must_check_this_out" and the number is: 0x1A5D215, then the output will be: 0x7cda66

The goal is to find an input string such that the following conditions are satisfied:

```
calc_hash(input, 0x1A5D215) == 0xd5
calc_hash(input, 0x28DB) == 0xe5
calc_hash(input, 0x5d1) == 0x19
calc_hash(input, 0xff7ff) == 0x53
calc_hash(input, 0x3eff) == 0x87
```

I do not know the length of the input string however the constraint on length is that it should be less than or equal to 30

```
len(input) <= 30
```

So, I wrote the following code to find the solution using Z3, however it doesn't work.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
from z3 import *

def calc_hash(input, num):
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(input)):
        result = (ZeroExt(56, input[i]) + result * 10 - 0x30) % num

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solver()

    input = [BitVec("input%s" % i, 8) for i in range(10)]

    for i in range(10):
      s.add(input[i] >= 0x20)
      s.add(input[i] <= 0x7E)

    s.add(calc_hash(input,0x1A5D215) == 0xd5)
    s.add(calc_hash(input,0x28DB) == 0xe5)
    s.add(calc_hash(input,0x5d1) == 0x19)
    s.add(calc_hash(input,0xff7ff) == 0x53)
    s.add(calc_hash(input,0x3eff) == 0x87)

    print s.check()

    print s.model()
```

The length of the input can be changed in the code to try different lengths.

Is there an issue with the above code?

Comment: Can you elaborate "what doesn't work?" What did you expect to happen, and what actually did?

Comment: @LeventErkok Juding from 5 minutes testing, it appears that the problem is either *too hard*, or the encoding *too inefficient*. Actually, I am confused on what happens to `calc_hash()` here. Is it automatically transformed into some `smt2`-like set of constraints, or repeatedly evaluated as an *"external function"* along the search?